# MMSE Virtual Poster Session

Tags: discussion

I mentioned as a comment to the [Town Hall Meta Post](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/52) the possibility of organizing a virtual poster session on the [Gather Town platform](https://www.gather.town) for the MMSE community.

I've found the gather town platform to be a lot of fun. We could hang up posters about your research or interests. I don't really know what else we could talk about that isn't already addressed in the chat rooms and other channels, so that's why I suggested this as an alternative to the Town Hall meeting.

For example, it could be a fun way to network with the community and get some experience communicating research, etc.

What does the community think?